# Using question mark instead of table name in PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, tablename

I need to know can I use question marks (`?`) in PDO prepared statements as table name or not.

```
$table = $_POST['table'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE ? SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE id = ?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($table,$id));
```

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: PDO::prepare() [pdo.prepare]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE id = ?'

Comment: Thank you @tadman for your suggested link

Comment: FYI, if you need that - most likely your database structure is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Aside from that simple problem, there is another one - your code smells of bad database design. In a properly planned database you would **never** need to receive a table name via POST request.

Most likely you are using multiple tables where you have to use only one.

Answer (score -3):

You need to bind the parameters like this:

```
$q->bindParam(1, $table);
$q->bindParam(2, $id);
```

[Source (see Example #2)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Close, but no. You can't bind table names in PDO even though arguably this is a massive oversight.